# Sending e-mails in django works locally but not online

Tags: django, email, smtp

I have crated a Django app that send e-mail with an outlook account. So far it works locally, but I am unable make it work online. Should I change something in the `EMAIL_PORT` or add anything else?

This is my settings file:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx@outlook.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

This is my views file:

```
 t = loader.get_template('email2.html')
 c= Context({'customer':customer,})

 try:
    send_mail('Thanks for your order', t.render(c) , 'chocolatchocolat@outlook.com',[email], fail_silently=False)
 except:
    # add not sent to my DB
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure the correct settings are being loaded in your "online" environment. You should not change `EMAIL_PORT` if it does work locally.

Answer (score 1):

If this works locally and you are using the same settings in production, this probably means that your connection from your live server to the smtp server is blocked, or the smtp server is rejecting requests from the IP range that your live server resides in.

Can you ping the SMTP server from the live server? If not, try checking your firewall rules and run a trace to see where the request is being blocked.

If the SMTP server is blocking your IP range (Possible if you are using EC2 or another cloud provider) then you may have to contact the SMTP provider (Microsoft in this case) and have them whitelist your IP.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that my own Outlook account was temporarily blocked for some reason. Thanks anyway!